# Check and summed if two or more checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have an 4 input checkbox tag, and 1 div tag to display a price if one checkbox is checked

```
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check4" />
<div id="price"></div>
```

What i want to do if only 1 random checkbox is checked it will display number 1,800 on div#price, but if 2 checkbox is checked it will summed become 3,600 and so on until 4 checkbox. But i really confused how to do that using jQuery. Any idea?

Comment: you'll need to learn some javascript

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Any code or function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `:checkbox` selector to assign `change` event on all thre `type = checkbox` elements, one can add `[value="None"]` while selecing `checkbox` elements to be more specific.
- Use `:checkbox:checked` selector to select the checked checkboxes.

```js
var val = 1800;
$(':checkbox[value="None"]').on('change', function() {
  var len = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
  $('#price').text(len * val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check3" />
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="check4" />
<div id="price"></div>
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan – I am confuesed too.. Let him give some inputs :)

Comment: Yeah, it like what i expected, i've already try using on('click') and combination operator between && and ||. Using length is never cross in my mind, sorry because i'm new in javascript

Comment: @JhonnyJr. — I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" value="100" id="check1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="21" id="check2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="22" id="check3" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" id="check4" />
    <div id="price"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var price=0;
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var len = parseInt(this.value);  
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    price+=len;
  }else{
    price-=len;
  }
  console.log(price)
  $('#price').text(price);
});
```

**JSBIN**

[JSBIN-URL](http://jsbin.com/givaberaja/1/edit?html,js,console,output)